# Appending to doxygen function documentation C++ instead of replacing

Tags: c++, doxygen

Currently using Doxygen 1.8.13

We have:

- abstract base/interface class
- multiple implementation classes
- need to generate external and more detailed internal documentation (driven by ASPICE requirements)

So, we doxygen-ate the abstract base class with the calling contract in `interface.h`.  This would seen by external documentation.

For the implementation classes, we want to add information related to those interfaces w/regards to the implementation functionality as seen by the caller.   We'd prefer to add this to  `implementation.cpp` above each function.   Again, seen by external documentation.

THEN we want to have add detailed design and implementation information including cross referencing GUIDS, etc. to maintain tracibility with requirements and test plans, etc.  Stuff nobody but QA and auditors want to see.   We'd like to have this in a separate file `implementation.dox` so as to not clutter up the code with too much (also we deliver some of our SDK as source and don't really want to deliver this information to customers).

So we'd have two doxyfiles, one that includes the `implementation.dox` and one that doesn't.

So the behavior I've seen:

- the implementation automatically inherits the brief and detailed documentation (unfortunately not the parameters) UNLESS you add more information, then it simply replaces.  So you can use `@copydoc <base method>` to get the original information then add your own.
- If in our `implementation.dox` file, we do `@fn <method>`, then this replaces both unless again, we use `@copydoc`, but we can't `@copydoc` the implementation information because we're apparently defining it.

So...is there a way to accomplish what we want without pre processing via scripting or whacky `#include`/preprocessor fun.  is there an `@appendto` or something like that?  Or are we trying something that is round hole & square peg?

Comment: Taking another tack, @snippetdoc may help us extract stuff from another file, but it seems to have problems with aliases in the snippet

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using ? can you give an example of the problems you face with `@snippetdoc` and `ALIASES`? Can you give an example of the code you want to document?

Comment: @albert  Version is 1.8.13 (as listed in the first line).     The alias in the snippet is `@SDD_ID=wonk` with the alias defined as `ALIASES += "SDD_ID=\xrefitem SDD_ID \"SW Design ID\" \"List of SW Design ID\""`   The error returned is "unknown command \SDD_ID"

Comment: @albert huh, `@xrefitem BLAH "SWDesignID" "List of Degn ID" SRS-SWDES-9999` in the snippet just ends up with ""SWDesignID" "List of Degn ID" SRS-SWDES-9999" in the html.

Comment: Well version 1.8.13 is quite old (December 29,2016) the current version is 1.9.6 so I definitely advice to update your doxygen version.